# Should I suggest moonlighting to my company's subcontractor?

Tags: freelancing, subcontracting, moonlighting

I work at a company that had subcontracted another company for engineering work. I have been in direct communication with various levels of management and technical staff of the subcontracted company, not as an authoritative figure or management, but simply a technical SME. I've basically been working as part of their team helping them with engineering tasks, specifications, test support, as well as code reviews. We're jiving very well.

I can tell that they are struggling to keep up with work demands, and in my opinion they could use another hand. I wouldn't mind the extra income. Would it be inappropriate to contact the management that I already know and suggest that I could do some moonlighting for their company? Obviously, I would need to work on a different project than the one contracted by my main employer, to avoid the obvious conflict of interest.

But I worry that even the mere suggestion would be a conflict, like they might feel pressured to appease my request in order to keep in good standing with my employer. I'm probably overthinking it.

Comment: If you're salaried at your primary job, moonlighting for one of their contractors or vendors gives you too many obvious ways to double-dip. IMO unlikely this would be approved ... unless person approving specifically prefers shifting more work outside of the company due to inside politics, or because of the way overhead is calculated in budgets. Worth a discussion with you really trust inside yhe company, who could comment on these things.

Comment: They're working for your company. How would your doing work for them be a conflict of interest? Why would you not work on the same project for them that you're working on for your company? Why would you ask their management instead of asking your own management? None of that makes sense to me.

Comment: @joeqwert maybe an example scenario will help: I work for Company A and they have contracted Company B to make hamburgers. My job for Company A is to fill ketchup bottles, and check on Company B's hamburger progress. I do this from 9AM-5PM. I happen to notice that Company B also sells miniature umbrellas, and I also notice they are falling behind in miniature umbrella production schedule. I suggest to Company B that they can contract/pay me to work directly for Company B from 6PM to 9PM to help produce miniature umbrellas.

Comment: Understood. But why wouldn't you offer to help them with the work they're contracted to do for your company? Wouldn't that make more sense? And why would that be a conflict of interest? Why would you offer to help them with the work they perform for another company? Additionally, you don't know that helping them with their CompanyB work would allow them to catch up on the CompanyA work. All it guarantees is that they'll get more CompanyB work completed. Assuming that will allow them to get more CompanyA work done is an assumption I wouldn't make.

Comment: Why don't you ask your own company's HR department? I have a feeling they'll say "No".

Comment: @joeqwerty. Because if I did that, then Company A would be paying Company B to then take that money and pay an employee from Company A. Why does Company A need Company B at all? And you can't see the potential conflict of interest? "As a trusted employee of Company A, I can persuade them to gives tons more money to Company B....and then I can persuade Company B to pay me a huge bonus/raise!" I don't know why any assumption needs to be made: I never said they weren't keeping up with hamburger production, just umbrellas. If it does/doesn't help with Company A tasks is irrelevant to this endeavor

Answer (score 6):

**This actually probably not a conflict of interest, but an HR nightmare.**

It's not a conflict of interest to act as an SME.  Freelancers and contractors work across companies all the time as SMEs.  Sharing your knowledge as an SME wouldn't create a conflict of interest by itself.  It would be a conflict of interest if...

1. One of Moonlight LLC's products is a competitor to one of your company's product.
2. You use your position at your company to strong-arm Moonlight LLC into hiring you, or use your first job to force Moonlight LLC into something.  **Or act like you do.**

**The real problem is HR, and the fear you'll blackmail Moonlight LLC.**

Most companies have a lot of rules about moonlighting because of #2, especially the highlighted part.  How does your company know you haven't promised to make sure Moonlight LLC gets it's contract renewed if they hire you 15 hours a week?

If you really want to do this you'll need to 1) check your employee handbook.  Many companies have rules against moonlighting.  2) Talk to your boss about it.  Remember to phrase it in a way that your company wins.  Such as "Moonlight LLC is overworked right now.  If I moonlight 10 hours a week we could get our work done faster." 3) Approach Moonlight LLC about it.

Comment: Note that #2 also applies not just for strong-arming Moonlight LLC, but also if you're actively buttering them up using your company's assets or resources (whether physical, time, or information), even without explicitly asking for Moonlight LLC signing a contract with you in return.

Answer (score -2):

Major conflict of interest. You need to decide which company you want to work for more and focus on just working for that company.  Also I wouldn't be surprised if the subcontractor is a poorly managed company. It's like you're on a luxury cruise liner and you're thinking about jumping on the 100 year old under manned boat sailing nearby.

Comment: 100 year old sailing boats can be a lot more fun than luxury cruises.

Comment: A lot of wild assumptions, though my question addresses most of them. 1) This company isn't a 100 year old manned sailboat: I've been working with them and enjoy it (ie "We're jiving very well"), so this is just another cruise liner. 2) I'm not "jumping off" my luxury cruise liner. To keep with your analogy: My current cruise liner closes down in the evening, and instead of just waiting in my cabin until morning, a neighboring cruise liner invites me to come aboard during evenings, and then return to my regular cruise next day. Both captains are cool with it.

Comment: @Philipp I don't actually have a preference (in terms of boats).  But in terms of earning a living: The point is you're making a choice that can end with you permanently assigned to just one boat. Regardless of your intention.

Comment: @SittinHawk don't think it's a wild assumption to say that a company that can't handle things is under manned. You wrote, "I can tell that they are struggling to keep up with work demands, and in my opinion they could use another hand."

Comment: @HenryM my scrutiny of your comment was not that you were calling it "under manned", I completely agree it's under manned, thus my suggestion to help out. My problem is you are assuming that I have to give up one job to do the other. You do understand what "moonlighting" means, right? Being swamped with work does not mean the company is awful. It could very well mean that the company is incredibly great. I have worked with the company: It is incredibly great.

Comment: @SittinHawk I've been in the industry for over 20 years. Of course I know what moonlighting means. You're free to do whatever you wish. I just voiced my view on your specific situation.